# Split kitchen sink cold water line to supply patio hose bib

Tags: plumbing

I live in a condo with a second floor patio. I want to set up a drip line for my planters, but the existing hose bib is in the garage and there is no good way to run a hose from it to the patio. However, the patio shares a wall with the kitchen, and the kitchen sink is on that wall.

My idea is to split the cold water line for the kitchen sink, and use as the supply line for a hose bib on the patio, which I will install through said side wall. I've never done DIY plumbing before, so I don't know what I don't know. Is this a feasible solution? Are there any gotchas I need to be aware of?

In the attached image, the hot water tap is in front; the cold water tap is in back.

[image: An image of two water taps coming up through the bottom of a cabinet. The hot water tap (front) has a two outlet valve. The cold water tap (back) has a single outlet valve.]

Comment: Drip lines are nice, but planters seem to sound small enough for hand watering.  Second floor might also mean others are below you so extra connections also mean extra failure/leak points.  It should be easy to do, but in this case you might want a plumber to do the connections.  Your condo might also require a plumber to do the work.

Comment: The advantages of a drip line is it will minimize waste and keep the plants watered if I'm away without having to impose on a neighbor.

Answer (score 3):

Usually condos require approval before any modification can be done to any exterior wall. (Even your porch or balcony is an exterior space and considered a limited common area.)

Since you intend to bore a hole through the wall you need approval from the management company and possibly the Board. A management company or a Board should use caution and diligence in deciding on approval. As such they would be most likely to require a complete explanation of the project and assurance that those performing the work are licensed and insured. ( That would not be you)

If you get approval, it would come only if a licensed plumber was doing the work. This is actually beneficial to you, since the work would come with some guarantee, as well as easing a great financial burden should something fail and damage others units. (The plumbing Co. would be on the hook.)

Your best course of action here is to call a plumbing co.  Get some work proposals that outline what they will do and what materials will be used. Also collect their license and insurance info.  Take that to management and the Board and ask for approval before any work is done.  ( You do all that and they will be impressed and more likely to approve your work.)  Then, when approved, have the work done and relax because if there is an issue, you did your due diligence.